# Scan single character C

Tags: c

```
/*
Program to calculate trip and plan flights
*/
#define TRIP 6
#define DEST 1
#include <stdio.h>

int error_dest(int type_num, int cont_num, int dest_code, int check);


int main(void)
{
  int check, type_num, cont_num, index, i, dest_code, trip_num, row, col;
  int travelint[TRIP][DEST], travelarea[TRIP];
  char area_code, S, M, L, N, P, K, R, C, U, W, O;

  trip_num = 7;
  while (trip_num > TRIP)
  {
    printf("Please enter the number of trips:");
    scanf("%d", &trip_num);
    if ( trip_num < TRIP)
    { 
      printf("Valid trip number. Please proceed to enter destination code.\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Invalid trips. Please enter no more then 6 trips.\n");
    }
  }

  /*********************************************************************************/

  for (i=0; i < trip_num ; i++)  /*destination code input*/
  {   
    printf("Please enter destination code:");
    scanf("%d", &dest_code);                   /*input of destination code*/
    check = error_dest(type_num, cont_num, dest_code, check);
    if (check == 2)
    { travelint[i][0]=dest_code; }
    else
    {
      while (check == 1)
      {
        printf("Please enter destination code:");
        scanf("%d", &dest_code);                   /*input of destination code*/
        check = error_dest(type_num, cont_num, dest_code, check);
        if (check == 2)
        { travelint[i][0]=dest_code; }

      }
    }
    printf("Please select from the following that best describes your destination:\n");
    printf("S Small city - population under 50,000\n");
    printf("M Medium city - population between 50,000 and 500,000\n");
    printf("L Large city - pop. over 500,000\n");
    printf("N Natural formation like a mountain, a lake, a cave, a geyser, a fjord, a canyon, etc.\n");
    printf("P Designated park or reserve such as a wildlife refuge, a national park, a bioreserve, or a protected marine area\n");
    printf("K Man made landmark like the Great Wall of China, the Taj Mahal, or Stonehenge\n");
    printf("R State or province or region of a country\n");
    printf("C Whole country\n");
    printf("U Multiple countries like traveling through Europe\n");
    printf("W Ocean voyage\n");
    printf("O Any other type of destination - such as visiting the sites of the seven wonders of the world\n");
    printf("Please enter the Area Letter code:");
    scanf("%c", &area_code);       

  }
  /*******************************************************************************/

  /*print for destination_code*/

  for (row = 0; row < trip_num; row++)
  {
    for (col=0; col < DEST; col++)
      printf("Trip[%d] = %d\n", row+1, travelint[row][col]);
  }

  return 0;  

}

error_dest(type_num, cont_num, dest_code, check)
{   
  cont_num = dest_code / 10000;             /*math for error check*/
  type_num = dest_code/1000 - cont_num*10;  

  if ( (cont_num <= 7) && (cont_num > 0) &&  (type_num <= 5) && (type_num >=0) )
  { /* loop for checking destination code*/
    check = 2 ;
    return check;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d is a invalid code\n", dest_code);
    check = 1;
    return check;
  }
}
```

for some strange reason at the scanf("%c", &area_code); it just runs ahead and print the dest_code array without letting me input any character and I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but when trip_num == TRIP you say it's invalid but then accept it.

Comment: `char area_code, S, M, L, N, P, K, R, C, U, W, O;` I see 11 variables that you're simply not using in your code.

Comment: I'm not sure I see where I accepted that.  the S M L N... are the selections to chose from the printf thats what the user was going to enter at the scanf area_code and  area_code was where I was going to store the single character

Comment: You might want to work on your formatting. What looked like the end of the function body was the end of the for loop. That really threw me off. Also, you are using `check` and `cont_num` without initializing them: `check = error_dest(type_num, cont_num, dest_code, check);`

Comment: @Thao Starting from `scanf("%d", &trip_num)`: user enters 6 (`TRIP` in this case), and now trip_num == TRIP. `if (trip_num < TRIP)` is false, so the program prints "Invalid trips. Please enter no more then 6 trips." At the top of the while loop it checks if `trip_num > TRIP`. trip_num == TRIP, so it exits the while loop and enter the for loop and print "Please enter destination code:" and proceed.

Comment: oh okay I see where your going  and I initialize all type_num/cont_num/des_code/check at the top of the main

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to grab only one character, perhaps it would be better to use getchar() instead of scanf()?

Comment: The only problem is our professor is really strict with not using material/func that she hasn't introduced which is the only reason why I'm trying to make scanf() work ._.;

Answer (score 1):

You may print `area_code` after scanf, I guess it may be '\n' which is the last character of the `dest_code` line you entered.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Thao Nguyen Use printf("%c", area_code); to see what area_code is

Answer (score 1):

Basically what's happening is this: you print the "Please enter the number of trips" message to the screen. The user types in 4 and then hits the enter key, which means the `stdin` buffer looks like this: "4\n". You then call `scanf` with the "%d" format string. `scanf` looks at the `stdin` buffer, and sees the 4. It looks at the next character, which is the newline, and sees it's not part of a number (as %d specifies), so it is done fulfilling the format string and leaves the file pointer at the newline. It converts the char '4' to an integer 4 and places it in `trip_num` and returns.

The next time you call `scanf`, it picks up where it left off at the newline. The format string this time is "%c", so it just grabs the next character from the buffer which is currently the newline ("\n"), places it in `dest_code`, and returns. If you want the `scanf` function to skip over the whitespace in this case, you have to explicitly tell it by adding a space before the "%c" format for the second `scanf` (destination code). Then `scanf` will skip over all whitespace (including that newline) until it encounters a non-whitespace character that it places in `dest_code`.

TL;DR: Change the second `scanf` call to `scanf(" %c", &dest_code)`. And fix the other errors others have pointed out so other bugs won't manifest.

Comment: Yea I think I see where you are going

Answer (score 0):

You should empty the buffer before reading a character from `stdin`:

```
int c = 0;
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
{
    c = getchar();
}
```

then you can read your character using `scanf` or replace it with `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help, but previously stated you probably need to put the getchar() into the while loop. You may also need the fgets to grab the stdin from the keyboard.

while(1){

```
 printf("Enter Message Type:");
 fflush(stdout) ;

//    scan msg.hdr from received message.
 scanf("%d", &(msg.m_hdr));
 while(getchar() != '\n'){}  

printf("Enter your Message:");
fflush(stdout);

// grab data from keyboard
fgets(msg.m_data, sizeof(msg.m_data), stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "**fflush(stdin)**" before you enter the character, i.e. before the "**printf**" statement for the character. *It will flush out the input buffer and thus you can scan the desired character*. Or simply give a **Space** before the "**%c**" command. Like----------     **scanf(" %c", &area_code);**    ---------------